# kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer. Connection works on other NIC/subnet

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I re-installed a VM (CentOS7) and now I get this error. The VM has two adapters that are on different subnets.
Funny enough **ssh worked fine on one subnet** after fixing the expected MITM warning.

ssh -v shows:

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "foreman" port yy
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to foreman [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port yy.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sam/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried

- Rebooting
- removing the known_hosts file
- checked /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the client (no deviation from maintainer version)
- checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server (no deviation from maintainer version)
- stopping the firewalld
- checked permissions on .ssh/ and authorized_keys
- checked blacklist and whitelist (nothing there, only comments) (hosts.deny|hosts.allow)

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the client is running arch linux

So, again to clarify
The server has two ip addresses 172.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x
ssh works for 172.x.x.x but does not for 192.x.x.x

Comment: Does the server have an /etc/hosts.deny file?

Comment: Yes, I did (I was still editing my post. You were really quick ;-)

Comment: What in your `/var/log/auth.log` file after trying to establish a connection? Also could you share your sshd_config file if possible? I'm assuming nothing sensitive is in there.

Comment: Here's a sample: `Jun  2 09:35:11 mxa sshd[24699]: Accepted publickey for myuser from X.X.X.X port 12345 ssh2: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Jun  2 09:35:11 mxa sshd[24699]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
Jun  2 09:35:11 mxa systemd-logind[1058]: New session 7084 of user myuser.
Jun  2 09:35:11 mxa systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)`

Comment: @ArcaArtem Everything looks fine. There are a few errors before and after, but related to bots trying to connect to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, that sounds like a routing problem or a problem with the netmasks. I have seen cases with a similar configuration, where the network stack tried to use the wrong interface for outgoing packets, i.e. where outgoing packets for *both* subnets were routed over the interface for the *first* subnet.

So the first thing to test is whether you can ping another machine in *each* of the subnets from the *server*, and vice versa. To make the testing process less error prone, you should configure the *other* machines (clients) to use only *one* IP address (otherwise, the test could fail because of wrong configuration of the *other* machines, which would be misleading).

The next thing would be a deep look into the output of `route -n` on the server and on the clients. Perhaps that already shows the cause of the problem. Would you mind publishing that output?

Furthermore, the output of `ifconfig -a` would be useful (again on the server and on the clients) - we'd eventually like to understand your netmasks.

When publishing those outputs, I think you don't need to obfuscate the IP addresses as long as they are from the private range. Obfuscating per se might be error prone, making analysis impossible.

If you decide to publish those outputs (please edit your question accordingly instead of using comments for that, because that outputs may be long), I'll have a look at it and try to find out what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your message. The issue in my case is that the server are available externally (so I can't post the IP) but also that they can be reached via ping. The ssh command fails, but if I repeat it multiple times, at one point it will succeed (from the first try to sometimes the 5th time). (by doing up, then enter to repeat the command in the term)

Comment: I didn't understand yet: *the server are available externally* What does this mean? I thought you have *one* SSH server with two IP adresses, and other clients connect to it. Connection attempts to IP1 are successful, while connection attempts to IP2 (mostly) fail. Did I get this right? Or is it your SSH server which is available externally?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I plugged in on the ticket but it's not my real issue. The problem is the same so I was thinking an answer to it would resolve mine.

Comment: Hi Binarus, I never saw your message when I was experiencing this issue and now I no longer work at the place I had this issue, so I'm going to assume it was indeed something with the routes not being set up correctly. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error under a slightly different situation. In my case the ssh-server was not installed in the first place, and straight install and start service fixed the problem.

The take home message is that these kind of error happens if no ssh is served on the port/ip/interface, whether due to installation or configuration.